# XSD Validation : Namespace causing root element to not be found

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

I'm trying to a update an existing schema to use its own namespace, so I can import it into another schema later and make it clear the types being used are from the imported schema.

I tried changing the default and targeted namespaces but it's caused the schema validation to break and hide the root node. From what I can see i've hidden my root element in another namespace but I am unsure how to configure this to get my desired result.

Here is a basic example of what I've tried

**XML**

```
<Parent Id="P">
   <Child Id="C"/>
</Parent>
```

**XSD**

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://myNameSpace.com" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" >

   <xsd:element name="Child">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="Id" />
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>


   <xsd:element name="Parent">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Child" minOccurs="0"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:attribute name="Id" />
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

**Validation**

> Not valid.
>
> Error - Line 1, 19: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 19; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'Parent'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few changes to your **XML**:

- Actually place the root element in the namespace given by target
  namespace of the XSD by adding `xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com"` to `P`.
- Optionally use `xsi:schemaLocation` to provide a hint to the XSD to
  use.

And to your **XSD**:

- Define a namespace prefix and use it to reference the `Child`
  declaration from the `Parent` declaration.

**Altogether then, this XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent Id="P"
        xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://myNameSpace.com try.xsd">
   <Child Id="C"/>
</Parent>
```

**will then be valid against this XSD,**

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://myNameSpace.com" 
            xmlns:m="http://myNameSpace.com"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xsd:element name="Child">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="Id" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="Parent">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="m:Child" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="Id" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

**as requested.**

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise the namespace has to be explicit in the XML as well as the schema. Unfortunately I'm limited by what I can change, and I cannot change the XML. Is it impossible use namespaces like this ?

Comment: Right, the namespace of the root element of the XML document must match the target namespace of the XSD you wish to use to validate XML with a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

when you have namespace in XSD you must have it in XML as well.

So, your XML must look like:

```
<Parent Id="P" xmlns="http://myNameSpace.com">
    <Child Id="C"/>
</Parent>
```

Or if you'd like to use prefix:

```
<mysp:Parent Id="P" xmlns:mysp="http://myNameSpace.com">
    <mysp:Child Id="C"/>
</mysp:Parent>
```