# XSD error: Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I tried validating my XSD file, but I keep getting error and cannot figure out the solution.

### Error

> Not valid.
>   Error - Line 41, 31: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 41; columnNumber: 31; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'CVType' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   Error - Line 50, 29: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 50; columnNumber: 29; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'detailType' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   Error - Line 56, 30: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 56; columnNumber: 30; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'NameType' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   Error - Line 67, 30: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 30; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'educationType' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   Error - Line 84, 33: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 84; columnNumber: 33; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'EmphistoryType' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   Error - Line 118, 40: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 118; columnNumber: 40; InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^[\w-_.]*[\w-.]\@[\w].+[\w]+[\w]$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'The range end code point is less than the start code point.'.

### XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">


<!--DECLARING ELEMENTS-->
<!--Simple type elements-->

<xsd:element name="fname" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="sname" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="position" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Type" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="PlaceObtained" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="place" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="DateStarted" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="DateFinished" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="intrest" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="reference" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>

<!--Custom Type Elements-->
<xsd:element name="cv" type="CVType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="detail" type="detailType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Name" type="NameType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Educations" type="EducationsType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="education" type="educationType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Emphistorys" type="EmphistorysType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Emphistory" type="EmphistoryType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="TechSkill" type="TechSkillType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="intrests" type="intrestsType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="email" type="emailType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="contact" type="contactType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="descripts" type="descriptsType"></xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ref" type="refType"></xsd:element>


<!--DECLARING THE STRUCTURE-->
<!--Defining the structure-->

<xsd:complexType name="CVType">
    <xsd:element ref="detail"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="Educations"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="Emphistorys"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="TechSkill"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="intrests"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="ref"></xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="detailType">
    <xsd:element ref="Name"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="email"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="contact"></xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="NameType">
    <xsd:element ref="fname"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="sname"></xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EducationsType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="education"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="educationType">
    <xsd:element ref="Title"></xsd:element>
   <xsd:element ref="Type"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="PlaceObtained"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="DateStarted"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="DateFinished"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5">
        <xsd:element ref="Description"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EmphistorysType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="Emphistory"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EmphistoryType">
    <xsd:element ref="position"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="place"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="DateStarted"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="DateFinished"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element ref="descripts"></xsd:element>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="descriptsType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="description"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="TechSkillType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="description"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="intrestsType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10">
        <xsd:element ref="intrest"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="refType">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5">
        <xsd:element ref="reference"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<!--Declaring types with RegEx-->

<xsd:simpleType name="emailType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="^[\\w-_\.]*[\\w-\.]\@[\\w]\.+[\\w]+[\\w]$"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="contactType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:pattern value="^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two categories of errors reported for your XSD:

1. > Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

   Element declarations (`xsd:element`) cannot appear as children to `xsd:complexType` directly.  Use `xsd:sequence`, `xsd:all`, or `xsd:choice` wrappers; looks like you probably want `xsd:sequence`.
2. > Error - Line 118, 40: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 118; columnNumber: 40; InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^[\w-_.]*[\w-.]\@[\w].+[\w]+[\w]$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'The range end code point is less than the start code point.'.

   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2147859/290085) for a valid email regex for XSD:

   ```
   <xsd:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/>
   ```

Comment: thank you for the reply that kind of helped me but now i am stuck at new error which is  **Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'cv'., Line '1', Column '5'.**

Comment: Make sure you understand namespaces.  See [***XSD Validation : Namespace causing root element to not be found***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41229156/290085).